# Trying to split an Alt tag in an Object and then place it all into an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have some products on a page that I need to grab the Alt tag from. I need to turn them into an Object. After that they need to go into an Array. 
I was thinking of creating a for loop to loop through the Alt tags, but I am stuck as to how to Split the Alt tag at the pipe '|'.I keep getting an Invalid or unexpected Token. This is code and below that is what I have.
Right at the end I have the jQuery version that works fine, but I want to know the Vanilla Javascript way. As I want to step away from jQuery and learn how to code better in Javascript.

```
<div class="product col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12" alt="0016|AUX Cable|2.39|5m|Black|2|Tech-Aux">
        <a href="/0016/product">
            <img class="productImage" src="/static/store/images/products/download-10.jpg">
        </a>
        <a href="/0016/product">
        <h3>AUX Cable</h3>
        </a>
        <h4 class="price">£2.39</h4>
        <input type="button" class="button style_one addToCartOne" value="Add To Cart">
    </div>
<div class="product col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12" alt="0015|USB 2 Type A|3.49|10m|Black|300|Tech-Usb">
        <a href="/0015/product">
            <img class="productImage" src="/static/store/images/products/download_Jb4ucER.jpg">
        </a>
        <a href="/0015/product">
        <h3>USB 2 Type A</h3>
        </a>
        <h4 class="price">£3.49</h4>
        <input type="button" class="button style_one addToCartOne" value="Add To Cart">
    </div>
```

Here is my code:

```
var products = document.querySelectorAll('.product');
  for(var i=0; i<products.length; i++){
  products[i].alt.split(“|”);}
```

Thank you for any advise. Also any help as to where I can look this up in the future would be great as well.

This is the jQuery code that works. And this is what I want to achieve in Javascript:

```
var products = [];
$.each($(".product"), function(){
var prodOb = {};
var prodDetails = $(this).attr("alt").split("|");
prodOb.id = prodDetails[0];
prodOb.name = prodDetails[1];
prodOb.price = prodDetails[2];
prodOb.brand = "Some Company";
products.push(prodOb)
})
console.log(products)
```

Comment: `products[i].alt.split(“|”)` if this is your actual code, those quotes are not ASCII quotes, therefore they cannot delimit a string.

Comment: You're not saving the result of the call to `split` anywhere. Also, you're using fancy quotes, but JavaScript requires boring old ASCII `"` quotes. (Also, you're putting the `}` in a very unusual place making editing the code extremely hard, but that's not actually causing *this* problem... :-) )

Comment: *"This is the jQuery code that works. And this is what I want to achieve in Javascript:"* jQuery is not a language. If you want to do this without jQuery, the correct phrase is "with the DOM" or "without a library." You're writing *JavaScript* whether you use jQuery or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really close, you've done the big that people find tricky (using the DOM instead of jQuery to find the elements).

Two things:

1. You seem to have stopped in the middle. You have the code using jQuery to do this, and most of that code has nothing to do with jQuery, but you haven't used that code in your attempt.
2. You're using fancy quotes (`“”`), but JavaScript requires boring straight up-and-down quotes (`"`).

If we just copy the code from the sample using jQuery into the code you've already written, and fix the quotes, use `elements` instead of `products` to conflict with the array you're creating, use a reasonable placement for `}`, and add a missing semicolon or two, we get:

```
var products = [];
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.product');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    var prodDetails = elements[i].getAttribute("alt").split("|");
    var prodOb = {};
    prodOb.id = prodDetails[0];
    prodOb.name = prodDetails[1];
    prodOb.price = prodDetails[2];
    prodOb.brand = "Some Company";
    products.push(prodOb);
}
console.log(products);
```

Or we can use `Array.prototype.map`, but for one it isn't a lot more concise:

```
var products = Array.prototype.map.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('.product'),
    function(element) {
        var prodDetails = elements.getAttribute("alt").split("|");
        return {
            id: prodDetails[0],
            name: prodDetails[1],
            price: prodDetails[2],
            brand: "Some Company"
        };
    }
);
console.log(products);
```

---

Note: We have to use `.getAttribute("alt")` instead of `.alt` because the HTML is invalid. `div` elements have no `alt` attribute. I have to admit in the first version of this question I didn't look at the HTML and assumed that it was valid, where the `alt` attribute is used on an `img` element (which has the `.alt` property).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I just have one question when I try and run the code of your first example i get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:4:39

Comment: @FrankBayers: I've updated the code in the answer. I didn't realize the elements in question were `div`s not `img`s (the HTML is invalid). See the note at the end. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a  legend!